# Ubuntu 20.04 long time during user login to desktop

Tags: 20.04, gnome, login

I have Ubuntu 20.04 in my laptop, and it have fastest boot time about only 14 seconds to reach user space, but after entering password to login, it takes nearly 45 seconds to reach desktop.

I tried after deleting .local , .config, .gconf still it takes 45 seconds.

1. Why it takes that much time?
2. What is the solution to reduce the login time?

And i have given the syslog [here](https://github.com/ms-jagadeeshan/log/blob/main/syslog).
Below are some lines of log, where it takes much time.

```
Jul  2 21:15:55 turing-machine /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[8093]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
Jul  2 21:15:55 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Jul  2 21:15:56 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for ClipboardIndicator#012get@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:287:29#012_init@/home/jaga_matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com/extension.js:88:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/_legacy.js:82:27#012enable@/home/jaga_matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com/extension.js:860:26#012_callExtensionEnable@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:167:32#012loadExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:351:26#012_loadExtensions/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:601:18#012collectFromDatadirs@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/fileUtils.js:27:17#012_loadExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:576:19#012_enableAllExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:610:18#012_sessionUpdated@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:641:18#012init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:56:14#012_initializeUI@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:257:22#012start@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:146:5#012@<main>:1:47
Jul  2 21:15:56 turing-machine dbus-daemon[7766]: [session uid=1000 pid=7766] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.47' (uid=1000 pid=8088 comm="/usr/libexec/evolution-source-registry " label="unconfined")
Jul  2 21:15:56 turing-machine dbus-daemon[7766]: [session uid=1000 pid=7766] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
Jul  2 21:15:56 turing-machine dbus-daemon[7766]: [session uid=1000 pid=7766] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5'
Jul  2 21:15:56 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Started Evolution source registry.
Jul  2 21:15:56 turing-machine dbus-daemon[7766]: [session uid=1000 pid=7766] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar8' unit='evolution-calendar-factory.service' requested by ':1.46' (uid=1000 pid=8082 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-shell-calendar-server " label="unconfined")
Jul  2 21:15:56 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Starting Evolution calendar service...
Jul  2 21:15:56 turing-machine dbus-daemon[7766]: [session uid=1000 pid=7766] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer'
Jul  2 21:15:56 turing-machine dbus-daemon[7766]: [session uid=1000 pid=7766] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar8'
Jul  2 21:15:56 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Started Evolution calendar service.
Jul  2 21:15:56 turing-machine dbus-daemon[7766]: [session uid=1000 pid=7766] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook10' unit='evolution-addressbook-factory.service' requested by ':1.49' (uid=1000 pid=8102 comm="/usr/libexec/evolution-calendar-factory " label="unconfined")
Jul  2 21:15:56 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Starting Evolution address book service...
Jul  2 21:15:56 turing-machine dbus-daemon[7766]: [session uid=1000 pid=7766] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook10'
Jul  2 21:15:56 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Started Evolution address book service.
Jul  2 21:15:57 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: loading user theme: /home/jaga_matrix/.themes/Mojave-dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
Jul  2 21:15:58 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Device -> enx000e09876640
Jul  2 21:15:59 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: JS ERROR: Could not load extension locale: Error: Missing metadata.json#012createExtensionObject@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:283:19#012_loadExtensions/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:596:34#012collectFromDatadirs@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/fileUtils.js:27:17#012_loadExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:576:19#012_enableAllExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:610:18#012_sessionUpdated@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:641:18#012init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:56:14#012_initializeUI@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:257:22#012start@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:146:5#012@<main>:1:47
Jul  2 21:15:59 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: JS ERROR: Could not load extension schemas: Error: Missing metadata.json#012createExtensionObject@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:283:19#012_loadExtensions/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:596:34#012collectFromDatadirs@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/fileUtils.js:27:17#012_loadExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:576:19#012_enableAllExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:610:18#012_sessionUpdated@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:641:18#012init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:56:14#012_initializeUI@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:257:22#012start@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:146:5#012@<main>:1:47
Jul  2 21:16:01 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: initializing Reminder Alarm Clock version 39
Jul  2 21:16:01 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: enabling Reminder Alarm Clock version 39
```

```
Jul  2 21:16:07 turing-machine NetworkManager[854]: <info>  [1625240767.8427] agent-manager: agent[26b7620ccb38132b,:1.82/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine gsd-media-keys[10100]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:rfkill
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine gsd-media-keys[10100]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-random
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine gsd-media-keys[10100]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:hibernate
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine gsd-media-keys[10100]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-repeat
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Started GNOME XSettings.
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Reached target GNOME XSettings.
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Reached target GNOME Session.
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Reached target GNOME X11 Session (session: ubuntu).
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Reached target Current graphical user session.
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Condition check resulted in GNOME Initial Setup being skipped.
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Condition check resulted in GNOME Welcome Tour being skipped.
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Startup finished in 24.563s.
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine colord[957]: failed to get session [pid 10090]: No data available
Jul  2 21:16:08 turing-machine gnome-shell[3582]: Failed to set CRTC gamma: drmModeCrtcSetGamma on CRTC 51 failed: Permission denied
Jul  2 21:16:09 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Some code tried to set a deprecated GObject property.#0120 _patchContainerClass/containerClass.prototype.child_set() ["resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js":34:12]#0121 _patchContainerClass/containerClass.prototype.add() ["resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js":43:17]#0122 _buildMenu/<() ["/home/jaga_matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com/extension.js":133:34]#0123 readRegistry/</<() ["/home/jaga_matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com/utils.js":127:16]
Jul  2 21:16:15 turing-machine geoclue[5374]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
Jul  2 21:16:15 turing-machine systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Succeeded.
Jul  2 21:16:18 turing-machine AppRun[10160]: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3:22: Not a valid image
Jul  2 21:16:18 turing-machine AppRun[10160]: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:6:22: Not a valid image
Jul  2 21:16:18 turing-machine AppRun[10160]: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:12:22: Not a valid image
Jul  2 21:16:18 turing-machine AppRun[10160]: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:15:22: Not a valid image
```

```
Jul  2 21:16:18 turing-machine AppRun[10160]: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:10433:21: '-gtk-outline-radius' is not a valid property name
Jul  2 21:16:18 turing-machine AppRun[10160]: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:10539:11: 'min-width' is not a valid property name
Jul  2 21:16:18 turing-machine AppRun[10160]: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:10540:12: 'min-height' is not a valid property name
Jul  2 21:16:26 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Jul  2 21:16:26 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Jul  2 21:16:26 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Jul  2 21:16:26 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Jul  2 21:16:26 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Jul  2 21:16:26 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Jul  2 21:16:26 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Jul  2 21:16:26 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Jul  2 21:16:26 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Jul  2 21:16:26 turing-machine dbus-daemon[7766]: [session uid=1000 pid=7766] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=1000 pid=7761 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-extract " label="unconfined")
Jul  2 21:16:26 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Starting Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Jul  2 21:16:26 turing-machine dbus-daemon[7766]: [session uid=1000 pid=7766] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
Jul  2 21:16:26 turing-machine systemd[7751]: Started Virtual filesystem metadata service.
Jul  2 21:16:28 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Ignoring excess values in shadow definition
Jul  2 21:16:28 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Ignoring excess values in shadow definition
Jul  2 21:16:30 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: GNOME Shell started at Fri Jul 02 2021 21:15:55 GMT+0530 (IST)
Jul  2 21:16:30 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Registering session with GDM
Jul  2 21:16:30 turing-machine gnome-shell[3582]: Connection to xwayland lost
Jul  2 21:16:30 turing-machine ibus-daemon[5532]: GChildWatchSource: Exit status of a child process was requested but ECHILD was received by waitpid(). See the documentation of g_child_watch_source_new() for possible causes.
Jul  2 21:16:30 turing-machine gsd-color[10090]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_LG_Display_gdm_125
Jul  2 21:16:30 turing-machine systemd[1498]: pulseaudio.service: Succeeded.
Jul  2 21:16:30 turing-machine systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Succeeded.
Jul  2 21:16:31 turing-machine gdm3: Child process -2591 was already dead.
Jul  2 21:16:33 turing-machine systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Jul  2 21:16:33 turing-machine systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Succeeded.
Jul  2 21:16:38 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: Ignoring excess values in shadow definition
Jul  2 21:16:38 turing-machine gnome-shell[8019]: message repeated 11 times: [ Ignoring excess values in shadow definition]
Jul  2 21:16:41 turing-machine systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 125...
Jul  2 21:16:41 turing-machine systemd[1498]: Stopped target Main User Target.
```

Comment: Please add the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain; systemd-analyze blame | head -20`

Comment: i recently upgraded to 21.04, now its fine